# why innodb index length limit to 3072 when page_size is 16k?

Tags: mysql

why innodb index length limit to 3072 when page_size = 16k?

same questions with page_size 4kb and 8kb.

I searched and tried to find out from the source code, but I didn’t find the answer.

[image: index length limits]

Comment: Do you *really* have `1.2976974104486003465381359390312e+7398` distinct keys? You don't want index keys to be anywhere near that length. Anything much over 100 is suspect IMHO. Back in the day I wrote an ISAM whose maximum *record length* was 4096 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc#L6380-L6401 says:

> An InnoDB page must store >= 2 keys; a secondary key record
> must also contain the primary key value.  Therefore, if both
> the primary key and the secondary key are at this maximum length,
> it must be less than 1/4th of the free space on a page including
> record overhead.
>
> MySQL imposes its own limit to this number; MAX_KEY_LENGTH = 3072.
>
> For page sizes = 16k, InnoDB historically reported 3500 bytes here,
> But the MySQL limit of 3072 was always used through the handler
> interface.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_const.h#L47 says:

> ```
> constexpr const unsigned int MAX_KEY_LENGTH{3072}; /* max possible key */
> ```

There is no comment to explain why this number is used. Perhaps other storage engines besides InnoDB are limited to 3072?